# "Redundant" javadoc - desirable in public-facing APIs?

Tags: java, api, javadoc, soa, public-method

When you see something like this:

```
/**
* Gets the Person's identifier.
*
* @return The person identifier.
*/
public long getId()
```

a lot of you may think "what's the point of repeating what the code implies"? I personally agree, and would not bother with writing such a comment if my code was only seen and used by people in my company.

If however I was writing, say, an Apache Commons library I think it could be argued that it enhances the consuming programmer's experience. Seeing accessible methods with empty space in the javadoc just creates a feeling of a lack of friendliness/maturity/support to a consumer that can affect their confidence in your api and ultimately choose a competitor.

Is there a difference in desirability of redundant javadoc for public-facing versus non-public-facing APIs?

Comment: Note to self - 1) the comment above is helpful because it states what the identifier is for. You don't have to go to the top of the html page to see what entity the ID is for.  2) The presence of a redundant comment with nothing interesting is a stronger signal that there is no gotcha, than if there is no comment at all (analogous to "nulls in relational database tables could mean many alternative things").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean it as a library, then yes, all public methods and fields should be documented, because that's what the html documentation is generated from.

For a personal use or just private / protected methods, there's not much point in documenting what is self-evident.

Comment: Okay, those two extremes I agree completely. What about that grey area in between where you work in a team of people, perhaps remotely distributed geographically, but outside your team no one uses your API? I'm guessing there is no absolute right or wrong practice, you have to treat every case individually?

Comment: I my code, I usually don't document getters and setters and methods that are self-evident even from their name, but "routine" methods usually deserve it, as that what you will see in a tooltip in your IDE. But I guess that's all about personal taste and what you think is right.

Comment: Fair enough. Back to the public library extreme - what is the "official" reason you would document "obvious" for the html documentation? Is it because your audience may include very inexperienced programmers? Is it a user-experience enhancement to please the marketing department? Or that html documents are meant to be read as prose more than as code?

Comment: It's for the sake of consistency, I guess. When you are reading a generated docs page, it'd look kind of unprofessional to have undocumented methods there, particularly because there can be some catch to them, like that they return null in some situations, can throw a runtime exception, or just some implementation details and usage tips. If you have only the name and parameters there, you might wonder if it really does what you think.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks MightyPork.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much difference in what documentation is desired; you are wondering about a symptom rather than a cause.  In most cases that terrible documentation is because you are in one of two failure modes:

Maybe you have a method that does nothing, owns nothing, and causes nothing, so has no meaningful role in the product.  It only exists to serve as a way for a bag of bits to give data to someone else, instead of doing something.

This leads to the sort of comment you indicate: "all I do is give up meaningful ownership of my data, have fun with it."  There is nothing more to say because the method *does* nothing more.

Fix this problem by having your objects own their data.  Don't build accessors for someone to read it, build methods that perform the actions they require and manage the internal data.  Build rendering methods that the object owns, rather than where it hands dava oer to a third party system with a shrug.

The other possible cause is that you have a method that sounds really simple, like "get the customer ID", but in practice does stuff.  It has a purpose, it captures a pile of business logic, and you just wrote down the outcome in the description.

Fix that by documenting things.  Assuming this is more than just "read an ID", I need to know some more things about your API:

- is this a persistent identifier that I can store in my database, and use to obtain the person later?
- will it ever change?  when?
- is this universally unique or just locally unique?
- what happens when the number space runs out?
- should this be displayed to users, or is it strictly an internal number?
- are there any security considerations around this, such that exposing it might risk a security issue in the product?
- is this fast or slow -- can I call it in a performance critical location?
- how long is it valid for -- can I cache it at the top of a loop and use it throughout?
- which other related API can I pass this ID to in order to make meaningful changes to the system?

Right now I know that it has an ID... of some sort... that I might use to... dunno.  Identify things?  To, um, something, I guess?

Instead, I want to know that this is the unique ID, that it is stable, and that it is potentially reused so I can't stash it on my side without also subscribing to the "user deleted" notification, and that it requires a database round trip, but an O(1) database operation, so performance means a minimum of two context switches and a maximum of 12xRTT on the network.

Those are useful things that you should put into your documentation.  Then have `@returns the ID of the person` at the very end, as a capstone.  I need to know that, sure, but there is so much more I need to know to use this effectively and safely.

Comment: You should add to your list "What guarantees are there on the values of the ID? Can it be `null`? What would `null` mean?" I've started using JSR 305 annotations.  Writing `public setAge(@Min(0) @Max(120) final int newAge)` or the corresponding `getAge` accessor automatically populates the Javadoc with useful information.

Comment: Interesting perspective Daniel. I am a big fan of the Law of Demeter and would never return anything more than immutable or primitive data that is highly cohesive with the class itself.